# can I use context API as almost another source of truth in a project that already has Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-context, react-state-management

I'm working on a project utilizes Redux for managing states of the app. As we know, in Redux there is a principle rule called having only one source of truth which simply means there is just a single JS value containing all of the existing states of the app, called store. So in this store we kind of reserve every states with a unique parameter. For Example in the mapStateToProps function:

`const mapStateToProps = state => myInfo: state.users.myInfo`

As you can see, in this case `state.users` is get reserved as an object in the state of the app. However in another part of the project I need to work with another API which its response contains an array with property of "users" (BTW it can not get changed, it should handle in Front-End). So I cannot use something like `activeUsers: state.users` in another component and get back an array of active users.

My question is can I use context API state manager for the new part of the project to handle this parameter duplication issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter how that second `users` property is called on the server, nothing stops you from giving it a name like `redUnicorns` or `activeUsers` - these are variable names that *you* as the programmer give to things. Just in your `configureStore` or `combineReducers` call, give the whole reducer a different name:

```js
const store = configureStore({
  users: usersReducers,
  greenPotatoes: myOtherUsersReducer
})

// data will be `store.greenPotatoes` now
```

or if you are writing legacy redux with `combineReducers` (please read [why RTK is Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today) in that case and start using Redux Toolkit, which will reduce your code down to 1/4 of what it is now)

```js
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  users: usersReducers,
  greenPotatoes: myOtherUsersReducer
})
```

Of course it is generally possible to use Context next to Redux, and that is perfectly viable in dependency injection scnearios, the question is "does it make sense" - and I have to say that in your case you just seem to be missing that you can call things however you like to call them in your end of the code - completely independently of which name they have somewhere else.